# AngularJS ng-style &quot issue

Tags: jquery, angularjs

ng-style is adding `&quot;` automatically for background url value ,

**js**

```
$scope.url = 'https://background_image_url.png' in my controller
```

**html**

```
<div ng-style="{'background': 'url('+url+') repeat'">
```

When I use the `innerHTML` or JQuery `html()` function to get the html from view I get

```
style="background: url(&quot;https://background_image_url.png&quot;);
```

Notice the  `&quot;` surrounding background image url.

See http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/26199/ .

Does anyone have any idea, how I can avoid the **&quot;** in url background,
this html does works but is giving an issue in yahoo mail :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are converting html to text it is showing html entity as &quot
If you want to convert back to normal link you have to use replace method and pass this reg expression it will convert back to normal text.

```
var html = $('#quote_issue_div').html().replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"');
```

Comment: I don't think I have any other choice, I cannot use the style attribute as it will be a too much of a change in code.
I have added 
html().replace(/background:\s*url\(&quot;(.*?)&quot;\)/g,"background: url($1)");
thanks for the help Chellappan & @ratherblue :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a great solution, but avoiding ngStyle will fix the issue. If you change:

```
ng-style="{'background': 'url('+url+')','height':'200px', 'border':'1px solid', 'width':'400px'}"
```

to

```
style="background-image: url({{url}}); height: 200px; border: 1px solid; width: 400px;"
```

then it works as you want it to. I'm not an AngularJS developer so it's possible Chellappan's answer is better.

Also, I played it with a little and realized this isn't an AngularJS issue per se. If you dynamically set a background image using vanilla JavaScript you run into the same issue.

Comment: I tried in http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/26265/ and it doesn't add the quotes.. at least it doesn't add them for me in Chrome. What's your PLNKR? Interested in seeing it.

Comment: How do you set the background image with vanilla JavaScript and get the same problem? It seems to me that AngularJS interpolation `{{ }}` has to use vanilla JavaScript as well.

Comment: Good point... not exactly sure why the interpolation works, but here is a vanilla JavaScript example showing the same issue: http://jsfiddle.net/qm9w804s/2/